# Rank(AB) and Rank(BA)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$A$ is a matrix of size $n\times r$. $B$ is a matrix of size $r\times n$. The rank of $A$ and $B$ are both equal to $r$.  Assuming $r < n$.

My question is: $\def\rank{\operatorname{rank}}\rank(AB) = \rank(BA)$?

PS: It's easy to prove that $\rank(AB)=r$.

Comment: The fact that you need to assume $BA\neq0$ means that you are aware of easy counterexamples, and wish to avoid those. But usually one can resuscitate such counterexamples by tacking on something simple (and extra row and column for instance) just to avoid the outlawed condition (here $BA=0$)

Comment: Yes...maybe what I wish is, under what conditions can 'rank(AB)=rank(BA)' hold true?

Comment: @Damon I've corrected formatting. Now you have possibility to extend your question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose subsets $I,J$ of size $r$ among $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, let $B$ be obtained by selecting rows with index in $I$ from the identity matrix $I_n$, and $A$ by taking from $I_n$ columns with index in $J$. Then $AB$ has rank $r$ but $BA$ has rank $|I\cap J|$, which is usually less than $r$.

To answer the question to characterise the cases where $BA$ does have rank $r$: the linear map for $A$ is injective with image (in $\Bbb R^n$) of dimension $r$, and that of $B$ is surjective with a kernel of dimension $n-r$; the rank of $BA$ will be less than $r$ by the dimension of the intersection of these two subspaces, so it will be $r$ if and only if the intersection is $\{0\}$ (they are complementary subspaces).